# Adding Projects in SVN using tortoise

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to know how to add my existing project in `svn`, checked some tutorials [tutorial1](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)
but none of them helped.

In the above link, they described some steps to create repository but i could do only till second step. After creating directories in new folder, i was trying to import files from existing project but getting the following **error :**

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///C:/svn/MyProject'
>   Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>   Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/svn/MyProject'

Comment: Where do you want to create repository and where do you want to check out

Comment: i just created my svn in cloudforge

Comment: You want create a repo on cloudforge and try to connect to repo on local C: ?

Comment: i created project in cloudforge and add svn service 
i want to export my project files to that folder

Comment: @SebinSimon if you have a repository on cloudforge, you need to tell SVN what that URL is.

Comment: yes i added svn url  then folder displayed in my system ?  but how can add files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*N.B. The TortoiseSVN menu is reached by clicking on the folder or file and then right click.*

1. Create your repository on your server *- Note the URL*
2. Clone to your hard drive TortoiseSVN->CheckOut *- from the same URL/trunk*
3. Add files to the directory **on your hard drive**, *by creating or copying*
4. TortoiseSVN->Add *the files this marks them as potentially part of the repository*
5. TortoiseSVN->Committ *this sends them to the URL*

Both before and after committing to the repository it is a good idea to also do TortoiseSVN->Update so as to frist get anybody else's changes into your copy and then to mark your copy as up to date.

Note that it is accepted as good practice to check-out at 2) our from *YourUrl*/trunk as this will help when you get into working on branches & tags later.

Comment: which folder for saving my files?

Comment: On your local hard drive start with an empty folder with a name reflecting your use e.g. `My_Project_SVN`.

Answer (score 1):

> You can create repo by using these commonds
>
> > svnadmin  create   --fs-type bdb   svnrepos/MyNewRepository
> >
> > or
> >
> > svnadmin   create   --fs-type fsfs   svnrepos/MyNewRepository
>
> Import Your Project
>
> (Assuming you’ve put your project files in   /projects/myexistingproject)
>
> svn   import   /projects/myexistingproject    file:///svnrepos/MyNewRepository

For more reference:

> [create new repo in svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html)

Comment: I'm thinking you should not recommend berkley db, but also you missed reading the comments and that he seems to have a repository on a hosted service.